# moist [mɔɪst] vs moisten [ˈmɔɪsn]

Tags: word-stress, syllables

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/moist):
moist /mɔɪst/
As we see, there is **not** an accent in the transcription.

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/moisten):
moisten /ˈmɔɪsn/
As we see, there **is** an accent in the transcription.

Why is it so? Is there any reasonable explanation about it?

Comment: Presumably they don't bother to mark stress for single syllable words? Whereas moisten has two syllables, so they need to show which one is stressed.

Comment: Did you look up any other one-syllable words on that website? Did any of those have stress indicators?

Comment: @Showsni I'm probably mistaken. As I understand, the number of syllables in a word and the number of syllables in its transcription may be not the same. The word "_moisten_" has two syllables, but the transcription [ˈmɔɪsn] has only one syllable. Therefore I can't understand how your sentence "_Whereas moisten has two syllables, so they need to show which one is stressed._" can make sense. In the first its clause you talk about the syllables of the word "_moisten_", but in the second clause you talk about the syllable of the transcription [ˈmɔɪsn]. Could you help me to deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean there is an accent in the transcription??

Comment: *" [ˈmɔɪsn] has only one syllable"* No it doesn't. It has two. Some accents/dialects pronounce the T as well, not all drop it. Even without the T it's *moy-sen* or if you insist, *moy-sn* or *sən* . [I don't speak IPA, sorry, because every time i do I end up in arguments with people who think it tells you how to pronounce things ;))

Comment: @gonefishin'again.: I think you misunderstand "syllable". The word "moist" is definitely a single-syllable (monosyllabic) word - but the vowel is a ***diphthong*** (feasibly ***triphthong*** in some accents).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - perhaps we have different accents/dialects & therefore pronounce it differently. I did say I have little truck with IPA.

Comment: @gonefishin'again.: *Moi non plus!* (That's why I don't know whether ***moisten*** might be a triphthong in some accents or not! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - In mine, even if I soften out all the rough northern edges like I'm talking to a Southerner ;) [i've lived in London 30 years, but Yorkshire for the first 30, so I can happily drift between them] it still ends in a very short 'sən', like bosun/bos'n. It's like one of those sci fi names where they put an inappropriate apostrophe just to make you halt half a tad, or someone's poor imitation of a Yorkshire accent, T'Pau.

Comment: [Completely off-topic] It reminds me of the Russian F1 driver Kvyat, who all the commentators insisted on calling 'caveat' because they couldn't get the gap short enough.

Answer (score 1):

The transcription of "moisten" has two syllables, and that website only indicates stressed syllables if there's more than one syllable. For instance:

> **jumble** /ˈdʒʌmbl/
> **welcome** /ˈwelkəm/

In /ˈmɔɪsn/, the "n" is a *syllabic "n"*, which means it's pronounced as a syllable. It's denoted in phonetics with the diacritic [n̩] (note the small vertical line below it).

Comment: You explained that there are two syllables in the transcription [ˈmɔɪsn]. The second syllable [n] is without a vowel sound, therefore [n] cannot have accent, since accent can stand only on the syllables that have a vowel sound. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking a separate question about the rules of stress, or is my answer about the dictionary's IPA transcription incomplete? If this is a different topic, feel free to ask a new question, or let's move it to [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow). If I'm online, I'm usually hanging out there

Comment: I'm sticking to the question from the original post. As I understand, the only place for the accent in ['moisn] is at the beginning of the transcription. That is, we even theoretically can't write [mois'n] because [n] is a syllable without a vowel. Therefore, to write the accent in ['moisn] is of no use at all. Do you agree? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii I see what you mean, but disagree. Not everyone knows what types of syllables can be stressed or not stressed, so it's quite useful to indicate stress in every word with more than one syllable. The only thing the reader needs to know is that words with one syllable don't have any stress marker, even if the word normally takes a stress in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

No stress symbols are used when it's just the IPA pronunciation for a monosyllabic word. I checked various dictionaries and they're all like this.

This can be seen easily in the [OALD pronunciation guide](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/about/english/pronunciation_english). In the charts, there are 3 polysyllabic words and those are the only pronunciations that have a stress symbol.

When words have both a [strong and weak form](https://multimedia-english.com/phonetics/weak-vs-strong-forms#:%7E:text=That%20weakened%20form%20is%20called,or%20when%20we%20emphasize%20them.), you'll see something like [/kən/, strong form  /kæn/](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/can1) in OALD. (Some other dictionaries show it similarly and others only show one pronunciation.)